# javaFX CheckBox isSelected from other class

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, fxmlloader

```
public class controller implements Initializable{

@FXML CheckBox chBox;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

......


  }end of initialize
}//end of class
```

i set up the check box in controller class and i made new editting cell class to edit tableview only if checkbox is selected.

```
    public class editingCell extends TableCell<TableView1, String>{

    public void startEdit(){

    ...
    }


    ...

    //i made checkbox status method
    public boolean checkBoxStatus(){
  try{
   Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("root.fxml"));
    CheckBox cBox = parent.lookup("#chBox")
        if(cBox.isSelected){
             return true;
             }
      }catch(Exception e){}


       return false;

    }

    }
```

but cBox.isSelected always return false even if box is checked.
how can i solve this problem??

Comment: There are several problems here. You reload the FXML file every time with `Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("root.fxml"));` which will create you a new controller every time. And also with this line: `CheckBox cBox = parent.lookup("#chBox")` you are getting the `CheckBox` from the scene-graph, not from the controller. As your `editingCell` class has a hard dependency on the controller, I would propose to implement it as an inner class and then you can get the `CheckBox` directly from the outer class.

Comment: *"i made new editting cell class to edit tableview only if checkbox is selected."* I guess binding the selected property to the editable property of the `TableView` was just too simple???